# Is it possible to import package in java dynamically?

Tags: java, import

I am developing Automated tests on Selenium Java and following is the configuration of my laptop.

Operating System:Windows 7 Ultimate.

I know the import line in java class appears after package line, like

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

but it there any possibility that an import line appears dynamically based on some condition instead of hard coded. As I have a menu:

[image: Menu image here]

and want to import and create driver instance based on user selection sent to the called method.
Like

```
public static void Setup(String browser)
{
    if(browser=="Chrome")
    {
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: `browser=="Chrome"` will not work use `browser.equals("Chrome")` instead

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to "localize" these imports, you can just use the fully-qualified name instead:

```
public static void setup(String browser) {
    if (browser.equals("Chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d:/chromedriver.exe");
        org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cd = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, no, there is no way to write `import` statements inside a class like that, they have to go at the top of the file.

By the way, you should compare `String`s with `.equals()` as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use fully qualified names as @pkpnd mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964768/5515060). You could split your code up into different classes and an interface which will create your webdriver:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public interface WebDriverFactory{
    WebDriver create();
}
```

And then the implementation for Chrome:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeDriverFactory implements WebDriverFactory{
    public ChromeDriver create(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d:/chromedriver.exe");
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Which will leave you with a nicer structure and less imports in your Setup class:

```
public static void Setup(String browser) {
    final WebDriverFactory factory;
    switch(browser){
        case "Chrome":
            factory = new ChromeDriverFactory();
            break;
        // other cases for firefox opera ie and so on

       default: 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Browser " + browser + " not supported!");
    }

    final WebDriver d = factory.create();
}
```

Overall you'll eliminate importing all the different drivers in your setup class. But you also split and moved the responsibility of the creation of the Drivers themselfs. That way the `ChromeDriverFactory` could for example add a lot more code than just setting a property and returning. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the State Pattern as following :

```
public interface Driver {
    void doSomething1();

    void doSomething2();

    void doSomething3();

    void doSomething4();

}

public class DriverHandler implements Driver {
    private Driver implem;

    @Override
    public void doSomething1() {
        implem.doSomething1();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething2() {
        implem.doSomething2();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething3() {
        implem.doSomething3();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething4() {
        implem.doSomething4();
    }

    public DriverHandler(String browserName) {
        swithDriver(browserName);
    }

    public synchronized void swithDriver(String browserName) {
        implem = DriverFactory.create(browserName);
    }
}

public class DriverFactory {
    public static final String FIREFOX = "Firefox";
    public static final String CHROME = "Chrome";

    private DriverFactory() {
        // hide default constructor
    }

    public static Driver create(String browserName) {
        switch (browserName) {
        case CHROME:
            return new ChromeDriver();
        case FIREFOX:
            return new FirefoxDriver();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

public class ChromeDriver implements Driver {

    // org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cd;

    public ChromeDriver() {
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d:/chromedriver.exe");
        // cd = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething1() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 1 with Chrome");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething2() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 2 with Chrome");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething3() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 3 with Chrome");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething4() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 4 with Chrome");
    }

}

public class FirefoxDriver implements Driver {

    public FirefoxDriver() {
        // initFireFoxDriver
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething1() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 1 with Firefox");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething2() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 2 with Firefox");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething3() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 3 with Firefox");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething4() {
        System.out.println("i do somenthing 4 with Firefox");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DriverHandler handler = new DriverHandler(DriverFactory.CHROME);
        handler.doSomething1();
        handler.doSomething2();
        handler.doSomething4();
        handler.doSomething3();
        handler.swithDriver(DriverFactory.FIREFOX);
        handler.doSomething2();
        handler.doSomething1();
        handler.doSomething3();
        handler.doSomething4();
    }

}
```

Like this each implem you have can make is own implem with all the import you want